# iphone/ipad with 2 side by side tables

Tags: iphone, uitableview, ipad

I want to create a landscape view with 2 table views side by side, using separate table controllers.

When I select a row, I want to move that selection to the other table. Initially I wanted an array, but I couldn't pass the array to the other controller. The array was a property of the table view controller.

I then tried to write the selection to core data, but that is crashing. To simplify, I have 2 entities in core data, Person (with name attribute and to one relationship) and SelectedPerson (with just the to one relationship to Person).

I have added the following:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    Person *person = (Person *)[fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    SelectedPerson *selectedPerson = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"SelectedPerson"
                              inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
    [selectedPerson setValue:person forKey:@"persons"];
    [leftViewController.tableView reloadData];
    NSLog(@"Selection saved OK");
```

If I temporarily delete my left controller from the nib, this works fine and when I add it back, it opens with the selected persons. But with the left table view, I get the following crash log:

```
[49650:207] Record saved OK
[49650:207]-[Person compare:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
[49650:207] Serious application error.  Exception was caught during Core Data change processing: -[Person compare:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x3d33ef0 with userInfo (null)
```

***I have uploaded a sample application here [link text](http://www.mediafire.com/file/zzldm1nmt2m/PersonsSample.zip)

I've seen apps that use side by side tables, but I'm struggling to get this working. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out - I didn't create `controllerDidChangeContent` in the right view controller.

I thought because I was updating a different entity than in the `fetchedResultsController', it wasn't needed but it turns out it is. Probably because of the inverse relationship. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

To update a table view, just send it a `reloadData` message.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. How do I send reloadData to a view that's already open with another view controller? Ie, 2 columns side by side, controlled by left view controller and right view controller. I want to add on didSelectRow on leftViewController a reload to the rightViewController.

Comment: `[rightViewController.tableView reloadData]` or however you call the property to your table view.

Comment: I apologize for my noobiness... what would be the line before this? If I'm creating a new controller I'd have something like... 
RightViewController *rightViewController = [RightViewController alloc]; 

Then your line would work and I'd push the controller. But in this case the controller is already open. How do I refer to the other controller?

Comment: Of course, you need to store a reference to the rightViewController somewhere so you can access it later. So your `LeftViewController` class should have a `rightViewController` property that you assign when you create the right view controller (either in code or via an IBOutlet from a NIB file).

Comment: I tried that (via IBoutlet) and while I can reload the tableview, I can't pass the array (which I set up as a property). I went back to the drawing board and wrote the selection to the datamodel, but it crashes as I'm updating the entity for the left tableview from my right tableview. (if I delete the left table from the nib, I can select entries that are saved to the model and shown if I return the table view and restart..only to crash if I try to to update it again).

Comment: Hmmm, I'd have to see all your code to know what's making it crash. (BTW, would you mind using backticks around code so that it gets `formatted` as such?)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I've corrected and added a sample application to see it in action